# Quando usar "meio" e "meia"

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Tenho algumas dúvidas de quando usar as palavras referenciadas no titulo, em frases como:

- A janela está (meio/meia) aberta?
- Ela está (meio/meia) cansada.

Gostaria de saber como usa-las de maneira adequada a cada situação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Meio* é aí um advérbio (significa *um pouco*, *um tanto*) e é portanto invariável. Assim:

> A janela está **meio** aberta.
>   Ela está **meio** cansada.

Quando *meio* é adjetivo indicando fração, então aí concorda com o nome:

> Comi **meia** maçã.

Comment: Na gíria "isso é **meia** boca", da qual significa  "mais ou menos", então o certo seria "Isso é **meio** boca", pois significa "um tanto"? isso?

Comment: E quando usar **meia**?

Comment: @David adicionei mais qualquer coisa. Quando a _isso é meia boca_, não conheço a expressão.

Comment: @Artefacto  "meia-boca" é uma expressão informal usada principalmente em São Paulo.  Muito provavelmente desconhecida em Portugal.

Comment: Estás certíssimo, Artefacto. Mas acho que valha a pena notar que Machado de Assis já disse «Os olhos chisparam e trocaram a expressão usual por outra, meia doce e meia triste».

Answer (score 1):

Um caminho é aplicar o oposto. Meio fechado/ meio aberta. Meio cansada/meio descansada (metade/metade).
No caso da maçã isso nunca é possível porque, no mínimo, haverá um flagrante erro de concordância.
Um abraço

Comment: Não me parece que seja um bom teste: _ela é meio mulher, meio égua_.